# Разметка xml в Android

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

Есть такой код:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50px"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/top_bar"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="two"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50px"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

В главной layout размещены еще два layout с id (one и two). layout у которого id = one размещена сверху (так и нужно), а вот layout у которого id = two дожен быть с самого низу экрана. Но он встает сразу после верхнего layout у которого id = one.

Как разместить layout с id = two в самом низу экрана. Так чтобы и на планшете и на телефоне он был снизу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заверните все в `RelativeLayout` первый р**а**зместите сверху, а второй р**а**зместите снизу (управляется атрибутами `alignParentTop/Bottom`)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
            android:id="one"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:background="@drawable/top_bar"
    android:alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
            android:id="two"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```